# Unity: How do you get a cameras position to update when in a different scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

In my game I have a camera that I have to not destroy on load between scenes however the camera will change its position to follow the player in the first scene but won't change its position to follow the player in the second scene. The camera stops moving upon entering the second scene here is my code for the camera following the player:

```
private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0f, 0f, -10f);
private float smoothTime = 0.25f;
private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

[SerializeField] GameObject target;


void Update()
{
    
    Debug.Log(transform.position);
    Vector3 targetPosition = target.transform.position + offset;
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
}
```

Heres the code for not destroying on load:

```
public static Cameradontdestroy Instance;

private void Awake()
{
    //prevents 2 instances of the camera existing at any given time
    if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Does the whole player and its movement setup remain or just cameras or what? If its just a camera, would be an odd choice, it needs to be linked to the player and movement etc. as youve not explained how it all works you need to make sure everything is linked up as it should be to work. Such as if player which looks to be separate. Wont be the same player in the next scene

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so I figured out what was wrong on my own I left a cinemachine component on my main camera from before when I used cinemachine instead of coding my own player follow script.

So the thing causing the issue was cinemachine and even if you delete the cinemachine game object you need to make sure you also delete the cinemachine component that was added to your main camera.